# How to share the clipboard between Windows Server 2008R2 and a guest running Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, ubuntu-12.04, copy, buffer

I use Windows Server 2008 R2 with Hyper-V and a guest running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

How can I share the clipboard between Windows Server 2008R2 and a guest running Ubuntu 12.04?

***UPDATE***

What protocols do I need to connect these machines? I'd like to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> on Ubuntu, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> on Windows Server and copy text this way.

Nowdays I use WinSCP. So I create a file with the text and then copy this file. It is not easy and fast.

Comment: Buffer between what??

Comment: between host system(Windows Server) and quest system (Linux). I can do it in Virtualbox. But i do not know how do it in Hyper-V.

Comment: Are you talking about shared folders?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you mean "clipboard", not buffer. If that's the case, no Hyper-V doesn't provide clipboard integration. You would have to connect to the machine over a protocol that supports the clipboard, like RDP or VNC.

Comment: How to set mouse integration in Ubuntu? Is it real?

Comment: You need to install Hyper-V Integration services, which isn't possible for Ubuntu. A third party option is needed.

Comment: @danbig Given that all that stuff is available in the kernel these days, why is it not possible to install the hyper-v integration components in ubuntu? All that stuff was moved into the linux kernel some time ago.

Comment: Because Mircosoft, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "just create a buffer" between two VMs on top of Hyper-V (even when one of the VMs is the management OS, or host.)  You can create a network between them that uses a shared buffer.